# Redcarpet gem not working properly? - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

i have installed and setup Redcarpet gem for markdown with CodeRay gem for syntax highlighting.

My problem is that the

``` ruby

```

which in markdown would provide a code block,its loaded but not styled properly,actually there is no style on the pre tags.

here is the code in my **application_helper.rb**

```
 class CodeRayify < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def block_code(code, language)
      CodeRay.scan(code, language).div(:line_numbers => :table)
    end
  end

  def markdown(text)
    coderayified = CodeRayify.new(:filter_html => true, :hard_wrap => true)
    options = {
      fenced_code_blocks: true,
      no_intra_emphasis: true,
      autolink: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      lax_spacing: true,
      superscript: true
    }

    markdown_to_html = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(coderayified,options)
    markdown_to_html.render(text).html_safe
  end
```

then all i do is this

in other words this styling that stackoverflows does when pressing ctrl+K is not there in my case.

Answer (score 0):

There are no *attributes* of `<pre>` tag, if you mean that by saying 'no style'. I just recreated your example and I see that Ruby code is colored properly within `<pre>` block: keywords have their own styles, and everything like that. If you really do have an error, check your gem versions. I have coderay 1.1.0 and redcarpet 3.3.2 and everything looks fine.

Comment: what i am asking is for the code "placeholder" to have that grey background like above. not the text itself.

Comment: Ah, but you should add that kind of styling to your .css file. just add `pre {background-color: #eee;}` to it.

Comment: as i saw in a video that styling comes default, also do you have coloring on your line numbers by default?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/unvcj50L/embedded/result/ – that's what I have by default. Line numbers, colors of keywords, background for string literal. No styling for `<pre>` and font is not monospaced as well. Either you or screencast's creator is missing something – you should add some CSS for styling.

Comment: hmm why are your line numbers linked? is it default or you did that?

Comment: btw see here towards the end for proof of redcarpet giving that grey background. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmlOBANv-z0

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmlOBANv-z0&feature=youtu.be&t=303 – as I said, you should add styling to css :)

Comment: dude he is using pygments, i was talking about CodeRay,anyhow i got it to work better with pygments,far better syntax highlighting and yes i had to add the style manually, you were right on that! thanks for the help!